# Overlay Pop Up Box - Getting Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created the overlay content in my HTML page like so:

```
<!--OVERLAY POPUP-->
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="content">
                <img class="logo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p>The name of this sweet is: </p>
                <button class="closebtn">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Using JQuery I retrieve and parse through an XML file which updates the information displayed on the HTML page, putting it into a list. I have also added the code to make the click work for this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "uploads/data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            error: function() {
                $('#message').text('Please upload the XML file.');
            },
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });

    function xmlParser(xml){
        $(xml).find("vendor-one").each(function(){
            $("#vendor-one").append('<li class="sweet">' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>');
            $(".sweet").fadeIn();
        });
/*
                Enable the overlay to display. Code used from:
                http://hallofhavoc.com/2013/05/how-to-create-an-overlay-popup-box-using-html-css-and-jquery/
            */
            $('.show-popup').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
                var docHeight = $(document).height(); //grab the height of the page
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); //grab the px value from the top of the page to where you're scrolling
                $('.overlay').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); //display your popup and set height to the page height
                $('.overlay').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'}); //set the content 20px from the window top
            });

            // hide popup when user clicks on close button
            $('.closebtn').click(function(){
                $('.overlay').hide(); // hide the overlay
            });

            // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
            $('.overlay').click(function(){
                $('.overlay').hide();
            })

            // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
            $('.content').click(function(){
                return false;
            });
    }
</script>
```

For testing purposes the sweet names can be:

- A
- B
- C

I wish to be able to click on each list item separately and have a unique overlay display.

The overlay displays correctly however, I now need to find a way to update the text within the overlay to display:

```
'The name of the sweet is: ' + NAMEOFSWEET + ' Get it now.'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: in your example `$("#vendor-one")` is not displayed on overlay. Overlay is empty as your code. How does your overlay display the content of `$("#vendor-one")` ?

Comment: @AAmirAfridi No it's not displayed, the reference to #vendor-one is a div which contains the list items. The overlay is executed only on elements which contain the 'show-popup' class.

Comment: So you want to copy the list from vender-one to overlay and than update the text as you said? like `$('overlay').html($('#vender-one'))` and than change text as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Do you want this: `$("#vendor-one").append('<li class="sweet">The name of the sweet is: ' + $(this).find("name").text() + ' Get it now.</li>');` ?

Comment: @AamirAfridi no, I wish to be able to click on each list item separately and have a unique overlay display. With the text I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: Not sure what you are after mate :/  
Your question and comments are confusing

Comment: @AamirAfridi What do you not understand so I can explain. Someone posted an answer which I was going to work on but they removed it and they seemed to have the idea.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and for xml, for dummy ajax call, try this http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html